# how to add button on video player inIOS / swift ?? as shown in fig

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, button, video

how to add button on the video player in ios/swift.
for below codes, was able to run the video and it can be controlled with the play and pause button.for below codes, was able to run the video and it can be controlled with the play and pause button.

```swift
@IBAction func play(_ sender: Any) {
        if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "video", ofType: ".mp4") {[enter image description here][1]
            let video = AVPlayer(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: path))
            let videoPlayer = AVPlayerViewController()
            videoPlayer.player = video

            present(videoPlayer, animated: true, completion: {
                video.play()
            })
        }

    }
```

Comment: Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34209858/how-to-add-a-custom-button-to-avplayerviewcontroller/38964575

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add a custom button to AVPlayerViewController?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34209858/how-to-add-a-custom-button-to-avplayerviewcontroller)